# Handling muliple rows with insert trigger

Tags: sql, triggers, insert

I have a trigger on an orders table that inserts order details into the `order_details` table. This works when only one row is entered, but not when multiple rows are inserted at once. I have read multiple threads > on various sites about using a cursor, while statements, temp tables, etc. I have tried a few but no success. Any suggestions on the BEST/Easiest way to ensure I get all the detailed rows added when an order is placed.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[CreateOrderDetails]
ON [dbo].[Orders]
FOR INSERT 
AS
    declare @OrderStagingId uniqueidentifier
    declare @OrderType as varchar(50)
    declare @OrderID uniqueidentifier
    declare @LocationID uniqueidentifier
    declare @status as varchar (25)
    declare @vendorid as uniqueidentifier

     SELECT @OrderID = OrderID, @LocationID = LocationID, 
            @vendorid = vendorid, @OrderStagingId = OrderStagingId
     FROM inserted

     Begin

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

     -- Insert statements for trigger here

     Insert into [Brain].dbo.[Order_Details]

     SELECT     
        NEWID() AS OrderDetailId, @OrderID AS OrderId, 
        dbo.OrderStaging_Details.EcProductID,    
        dbo.OrderStaging_Details.Qty, dbo.OrderStaging_Details.Qty_Type, 
        dbo.OrderStaging_Details.Cost, dbo.OrderStaging_Details.Ext_Cost, 
        dbo.OrderStaging_Details.EnteredBy,
        NULL AS ReceivedBy, NULL AS ReceivedDate, NULL AS ReceivedQty, 
        dbo.OrderStaging_Details.OrderNote, NULL AS ReceivedNote,    
        dbo.OrderStaging_Details.UpdatedBy, dbo.OrderStaging_Details.UpdateDate
     FROM         
        dbo.Vendor_Assigned_Locations 
     INNER JOIN
        dbo.Vendor_Contacts 
     INNER JOIN
        dbo.Vendors 
     INNER JOIN
        dbo.OrdersStaging 
     INNER JOIN
        dbo.OrderStaging_Details ON dbo.OrdersStaging.OrderStagingID = dbo.OrderStaging_Details.OrderStagingID 
            ON dbo.Vendors.VendorID = dbo.OrderStaging_Details.VendorId 
            ON dbo.Vendor_Contacts.Vendor_ID = dbo.Vendors.VendorID 
            ON dbo.Vendor_Assigned_Locations.LocationID = dbo.OrdersStaging.LocationID 
               AND dbo.Vendor_Assigned_Locations.VCID = dbo.Vendor_Contacts.VCID 
     INNER JOIN
        dbo.Orders ON dbo.OrdersStaging.OrderStagingID = dbo.Orders.OrderStagingID 
                   AND dbo.Vendors.VendorID = dbo.Orders.VendorID 
                   AND dbo.Vendor_Contacts.VCID = dbo.Orders.VendorContactID 
                   AND dbo.OrdersStaging.LocationID = dbo.Orders.LocationID 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.Order_Details ON dbo.Orders.OrderID = dbo.Order_Details.OrderID
     WHERE     
        (dbo.OrderStaging_Details.OrderStagingID = @OrderStagingID) 
        AND (dbo.OrdersStaging.LocationID = @Locationid)    
        AND (dbo.Vendors.VendorID = @Vendorid) 
        AND (dbo.Order_Details.OrderID IS NULL)
     end
```

Comment: The whole point of using `INNER JOIN` is to be able to define the **join condition** right after the JOIN operator - so it should be `INNER JOIN dbo.Vendor_Contacts ON ...(define your condition here)....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This trigger is probably necessary to you

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[CreateOrderDetails] ON [dbo].[Orders]
FOR INSERT 
AS 
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;    
  -- Insert statements for trigger here    
  INSERT INTO [Brain].dbo.[Order_Details]    
  SELECT     
    NEWID() AS OrderDetailId, i.OrderID AS OrderId, 
    dbo.OrderStaging_Details.EcProductID,    
    dbo.OrderStaging_Details.Qty, dbo.OrderStaging_Details.Qty_Type, 
    dbo.OrderStaging_Details.Cost, dbo.OrderStaging_Details.Ext_Cost, 
    dbo.OrderStaging_Details.EnteredBy,
    NULL AS ReceivedBy, NULL AS ReceivedDate, NULL AS ReceivedQty, 
    dbo.OrderStaging_Details.OrderNote, NULL AS ReceivedNote,    
    dbo.OrderStaging_Details.UpdatedBy, dbo.OrderStaging_Details.UpdateDate
  FROM               
    dbo.OrdersStaging 
  INNER JOIN
    dbo.OrderStaging_Details ON dbo.OrdersStaging.OrderStagingID = dbo.OrderStaging_Details.OrderStagingID 
  INNER JOIN
    dbo.Vendors ON dbo.Vendors.VendorID = dbo.OrderStaging_Details.VendorId
  INNER JOIN
    dbo.Vendor_Contacts ON dbo.Vendor_Contacts.Vendor_ID = dbo.Vendors.VendorID 
  INNER JOIN          
    dbo.Vendor_Assigned_Locations ON dbo.Vendor_Assigned_Locations.LocationID = dbo.OrdersStaging.LocationID 
                                       AND dbo.Vendor_Assigned_Locations.VCID = dbo.Vendor_Contacts.VCID
  INNER JOIN
    dbo.Orders ON dbo.OrdersStaging.OrderStagingID = dbo.Orders.OrderStagingID 
                    AND dbo.Vendors.VendorID = dbo.Orders.VendorID 
                    AND dbo.Vendor_Contacts.VCID = dbo.Orders.VendorContactID 
                    AND dbo.OrdersStaging.LocationID = dbo.Orders.LocationID 
  INNER JOIN
    inserted i ON dbo.Orders.OrderID = i.OrderID
END
```

Comment: Seems to be working with this in place. Thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

The outer select statement where you are picking up @OrderID, @LocationID etc, is only picking the first row out of inserted which contains all the orders that are being inserted in the transaction that pulled the trigger.

```
Use insert into detail(...)
Select NewID(), Inserted.OrderID, ... 
From Inserted
inner join ...
Where etc
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. That's exactly what it was doing. After using Alexanders example I was able to get it working. Same advice from everyone who replied and all was right on the mark.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're thinking about rows rather than columns.  Dump the @variables, and join on `inserted`.

Comment: Thanks I did this as Alexander showed in his modified version of my code and it seems to be working now. Thanks again for your help